# SQL number comparison and aggregation

Tags: sql

and using snowflake database. There is a task I'm trying to solve but don't know where to start. I want to do calculate the percentage of BIDS higher than/lower than/equal to PRICE and the accepted price.
There are thousands of IDs, below is one of them. The example data has 2 bids equal to price(180), one bid higher than price (200), and one bid lower than price (100). The accepted price's difference in percentage with price (100/180 = 0.55)

```
ID,     PRICE,ID,   BIDS,ACCEPTED
2134323,180,2134323,200,FALSE
2134323,180,2134323,180,FALSE
2134323,180,2134323,180,FALSE
2134323,180,2134323,100,TRUE
```

Expected output:

```
ID,     PRICE ACCEPTED HIGHER LOWER EQUAL
2134323 180    0.55      0.25   0.25  0.5
```

Any suggestion how to complete this?

Comment: Consider a 5th bid of 110, Are the expected results id, 180, .55, .20, .40, .40 ??  What about the case where the lowest bid was from multiple people?

Comment: @donPablo yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should work:

```
select id, price
       max(case when accepted = 'TRUE' then bids end) / price as accepted,
       avg(case when bids > price then 1.0 else 0 end) as higher,
       avg(case when bids < price then 1.0 else 0 end) as lower,
       avg(case when bids = price then 1.0 else 0 end) as equal
from t
group by id, price;
```

Comment: @Osca . . . It provides a ratio, as in your question.